# Cascading dropdown using Case Statement in SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have front end application that users my select either City name from drop down box or State name from another drop down box.  If users select ALL from the State drop down then the query should return all the States and the same thing is true  for the  City.  The table has other info like zip code so the query should always return a result based on the user selection.  The table is huge like over 100k rows so I want query that performs efficiently when checking the conditions.  The issue with this query is if I select California from the State dropdown and I want to select LA from the City dropdown then the query will not work.  Please help.  Thanks
here is my code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [MJX].[spx_Get_SL]
      @Filter_State VARCHAR(50),
      @Filter_City VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF @Filter_State <> 'ALL' 
            SELECT * FROM myTable  WHERE State = @Filter_State

   ELSE IF  @Filter_City <> 'ALL'
        SELECT * from myTable WHERE City=@Filter_City

      ELSE
        SELECT * from myTable
END
```

Comment: you need more if's, if `(St=ALL AND City=ALL)` `(St=ALL AND City<>ALL)` `(St<>ALL AND City=ALL)` `(St<>ALL AND City<>ALL)` and have dfferent behaviours for each case.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your parameter values into a single query:

```
select * from myTable 
Where (City = @FilterCity or @FilterCity = 'ALL') 
and (State = @FilterState or @FilterState = 'ALL')
```

A slightly more preferred option that avoids parameter sniffing and optimizes the query a tiny bit:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [MJX].[spx_Get_SL]
      @Filter_State VARCHAR(50),
      @Filter_City VARCHAR(50)
AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @LocFilter_State VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @LocFilter_Cty VARCHAR(50);

SELECT @LocFilter_State = CASE WHEN @Filter_State = 'ALL' THEN NULL else @Filter_State END;
SELECT @LocFilter_City = CASE WHEN @Filter_City = 'ALL' THEN NULL else @Filter_City END;

SELECT * from MyTable Where City = ISNULL(@LocFilter_City,City) AND State = ISNULL(@LocFilter_State,State);

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could this using a `Case` in your `Where` clause. So I am checking the value of your variable and then selecting the appropriate column or pass a 1

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE CASE 
        WHEN @Filter_State <> 'ALL'
            THEN STATE
        ELSE 1
        END = CASE 
        WHEN @Filter_State <> 'ALL'
            THEN @Filter_State
        ELSE 1
        END
    AND CASE 
        WHEN @Filter_City <> 'ALL'
            THEN City
        ELSE 1
        END = CASE 
        WHEN @Filter_City <> 'ALL'
            THEN @Filter_City
        ELSE 1
        END
```